# CPU Usage while packet forwarding

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

I'm trying to measure the CPU usage on a dual core ARM Cortex A9 processor to benchmark a it. It will be used a router. I enabled ip forwarding and I'm running iperf tests along with monitoring the CPU usage using top. I'm a little confused about interpreting the results from ***top***.

```
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 59.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 40.5%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

1) During packet forwarding why is the kernel usage at 0.5% compared to softirq percentage 40.5%? So the effective CPU usage is (40.5 + 0.5)%?

2) Why is the 2nd CPU completely idle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means that process context kernel usage is 0.5% i.e. non
   IRQ/Softirq usage in kernel is 0.5%. 40.5% is softirq as you clearly
   say. Effective CPU usage is as you say
2. probably because either you
   a) have only one hard irq for your
   network device and that's tied to core 0 or
   b) all IRQs are tied to core 0 even if you have more than one IRQ line/have
   multi-queue
   c) Your benchmark has a single TCP/UDP stream so the hashing is putting
   everything on core 0 even though you have multiple queue/cores.